# React-Native: How to know when the rendering got finished

Tags: react-native

I have `FlatList` in `render()` function with a reference,

```
 <FlatList
    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref }}
    data={this.state.data}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderOuterCard(item, index)}
/>
```

I need to use `this.flatListRef` to call `FlatList's` methods, which is possible only when `FlatList` is rendered. Otherwise following error occurs,

> Cannot read the property 'ScrollToIndex' of undefined

(I tried to call `FlatList's` `ScrollTOIndex` method)

Infact I called `ScrollTOIndex` in `componentDidMount()` method , But still this error occurs. Hence, This is clear that `componentDidMount()` is called before `render()` finishes completely.

Can anybody let me know when rendering finishes exactly?

Comment: have you tried like if(this.flatListRef) then do your code otherwise dont execute or, do a setTimeout

Comment: @GauravRoy I ma already using `setTimeout`, But time varies based on the content inside render. For example rendering time may vary for rendering 50 items , 100 items. Need an exact way to know rendering got finished.

Comment: @GauravRoy if i use `if(this.flatListRef)` error can be prevented, But the content inside `If` will never be called as `componentDidMount' is called only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is clear that componentDidMount() is called before render() finishes completely.

According to this schema the first `render` phase occur *before* `componentDidMount`.
http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

[image]

### Live example:

https://snack.expo.io/@flexbox/flatlist-with-state-example

Comment: You are right, `componentDidMount` is called after `render()` only. I was under wrong assumption. Thank You for answer.

Comment: If there is large content to render, Will `componentDidMount()` wait until all the rendering finished?. Still I am getting the error mentioned in the question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Kishore
Can you provide an example of your entire file on https://snack.expo.io/ ?

Comment: I have many `api` calls in my code which I cannot share. Is it ok if i share only `render()`

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue. I do have a Component that uses FlatList and I would like to know when, within the first render, the list has rendered the visible items (ready state).

I have discovered that on the main component the `componentDidMount` was triggered because the FlatList component have mounted as well. And because FlatList Component asyncronously renders each item they only show up after on `componentDidUpdate`.

I have struggled for a while and even with the `componentDidUpdate` approach I could only get the moment where FlatList got new data (not rendered the items).

So I found out that I could intercept the `renderItem` method to create some logic to better estimate what and when is being rendered. The other option was to have a `setTimeout` (very hacky) to trigger the work based on a average time (very poor solution).

If someone have a proper approach to be able to know when the FlatList finishes rendering the inView items please share.

Thanks.

Comment: I just edit my answer with https://snack.expo.io/@flexbox/flatlist-with-state-example
Let me know if there is a misunderstanding :)

Comment: @DavidLeuliette, thank you for your time. But I cannot understand where in your example, we can know when the visible items have rendered. I can see that you start providing the data after the FlatList mounts, but that happens before the render start.